# Integration Test - This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, iis, integration-testing

I am using VS 2015 with.Net 4.6.1. I am trying to write an integration test for a code but it's giving me above error. I cant get my head around. This method is in global.asax

```
public void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddCorsResponseHeadersForUnauthorizedRequests(Response, Request);
        }

        public static void AddCorsResponseHeadersForUnauthorizedRequests(HttpResponse response, HttpRequest request)
        {
            var origin = request.Params[AppConstant.RequestHttpOrigin];
            if (response.StatusCode == (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized &&
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Headers[AppConstant.AccessControlAllowOrigin]) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(origin))
            {
                response.AddHeader(AppConstant.AccessControlAllowOrigin, WebApiConfig.GetCorsAllowedOrigin());
                response.AddHeader(AppConstant.AccessControlAllowCredentials, "true");
            }
        }
```

> IntegrationTest.cs

```
[TestFixture]
    public class AuthenticationResponseHeadersTests
    {
        private WebApiApplication systemUnderTest;
        private HttpRequest httpRequest;
        private HttpResponse httpResponse;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            systemUnderTest = new WebApiApplication();
            httpRequest = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, "http://localhost:5001/", string.Empty);
            httpResponse = new HttpResponse(TextWriter.Null);
            httpResponse.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldAddCorsResponseHeaders()
        {
            httpResponse.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            WebApiApplication.AddCorsResponseHeadersForUnauthorizedRequests(httpResponse, httpRequest);

            Assert.AreEqual("http://localhost:5001", httpResponse.Headers[AppConstant.AccessControlAllowOrigin]);
            Assert.AreEqual("true", httpResponse.Headers[AppConstant.AccessControlAllowCredentials]);
        }
    }
```

The error I get is on if condition where it's trying to get the specific header for the Response.Headers and the error are, any idea? why does it need IIS for Test?

> This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode

[image]

Comment: what is your pipeline?

Comment: @PouyaSamie I am using IIsExpress but I can deploy it on full IIs and check if it fixes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic mode (the only mode in IIS6 and below) is a mode where IIS only works with ISAPI extensions

Integrated mode, on the other hand, is a new mode in IIS7 where IIS pipeline is tightly integrated (i.e. is just the same) as ASP.NET request pipeline

select the Web Application project node in Solution Explorer and Press F4 and change your Pipeline [image]

By the way, because you are using Web API there is no need to be worry about HttpModule and HttpHandlers because their section has been changed in web configure in Integrated pipeline mode.

**UPDATE** I will suggest Use IHttpContext and write your own wrapper with an interface for them like say IHttpContext. Then you just have your own HttpContext and delegate all the calls to it. Then in your app everyone uses the interface. This fixes your problem with interacting with Microsofts sealed classes because you can substitute mocks or stubs or whatever.

Check This link :
http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/09/ihttpcontext-and-other-interfaces-for-your-duck-typing-benefit.aspx/

Comment: I am using IISExpress, do I need to use full IIS? well everything is localhost so I can try creating a website in IIS.

Comment: no just the express iis will do ... change the pipeline and you should be fine

Comment: actually I just verified that I indeed have integrated pipeline in properties, anonymous is disabled and windows is enabled.

Comment: do I need to write something in app.config? in integrationTest project?

Comment: Check my Update

Comment: I dont want to write so much code just to test a response header...I thought i could get away with that. HttpRequest and HttpReponse are just classes and should not have dependency on IIS.